# using pointer to pass scanf from function to main

Tags: c

so in here, i'm trying to pass the dokter value to main function, and from what i know, function can only return one value at a time, so is there any other way to return the dokter value to main function?
Any help/advice will be appreciated, thanks!

```
void booking(int argc, char** argv){
    int *dokter;
    system("cls");

    printf("\nSilahkan pilih Dokter yang tersedia\n1. Dr. Saburo\n2. Dr. Bineka\n3. Dr. Saskeh\n4. Dr. Lur Bor\n5. Dr. Frutang");
    printf("\nPilih (1/2/3/4/5) >: ");
    scanf("%d", &dokter);

    if(dokter == 1){
        printf("Hari yang tersedia : Senin, Rabu, Kamis, Jumat");
    } else if(dokter == 2){
        printf("Hari yang tersedia : Selasa, Rabu, Jumat, Sabtu");
    } else if(dokter == 3){
        printf("Hari yang tersedia : Senin, Rabu, Kamis, Sabtu, Minggu");
    } else if(dokter == 4){
        printf("Hari yang tersedia : Senin, Kamis, Jumat");
    } else if(dokter == 5){
        printf("Hari yang tersedia : Selasa, Rabu, Sabtu, Minggu");
    } else{
        printf("Invalid");
    }

    jadwal = (char*) malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    printf("\nJadwal >: ");
    scanf(" %101[^\n]s", jadwal);
    return jadwal;
    free(jadwal);
}
```

Comment: `int *dokter;` --> `int dokter;`

Comment: `booking` has a `void` return signature, yet you try to return a value

Comment: once you `return`, the the function is done, `free(jadwal);` will never be reached (that makes little sense there anyway).

Comment: Save time and enable all compiler warnings as with `int *dokter; ...  scanf("%d", &dokter);`.

Comment: Why `101` in `" %101[^\n]s"`? Who or what text suggested a `s` in  `" %101[^\n]s"`?

Comment: For your actual question, you're right that a function can only return one value. If you want to "return" more, you need to pass in a pointer to each value, dereference and set it in the function. So you should do `int dokter` in `main`, change your function signature to accept an `int*`, and pass in the address of `dokter` like `&dokter`

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options, here's two:

1. Make a struct, which contains members of what you want to return. In your case it looks like you want to return a `char*` and an `int`.

```c
struct MyStruct {
    char* string;
    int foo;
};
```

2. Make one or more of the things you are returning a global variable.

```c
int *dokter;

...

void booking(int argc, char** argv){
    system("cls");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Quite a few things:

- `int *dokter;` does not allocate any memory for an `int`, but rather memory for the address of an `int`. This should simply be `int dokter;`.
- The *field-width specifier* in `scanf("%101[^\n]s", jadwal)` should be *one less* than the size of your buffer, which would be `99`. Additionally, `%[]` and `%s` are two different specifiers. `%[]s` is the first of these, followed by a literal `s`.

  - You must also consider that the previous `scanf` has left the newline in the buffer, and as such a properly formatted specifier of `%99[^\n]` will immediately halt, having read in no characters. Consume the newline with `%*c` (match a single character, discarding the result), or other means.
- `jadwal` has no type information.
- `sizeof (char)` is always `1`.
- `free(jadwal);` will never be reached, as it is after your `return` statement. Why free the memory you just initialized and intended to return? This should be handled by the caller.
- `booking` has the return type of `void`, but attempts to return something.
- Newlines generally go at the *end* of a line.

To 'return' multiple values from a function, you can use pointers as its arguments. It is up to the caller to provide the addresses of where these values will be stored (this is exactly how the variadic arguments of the `scanf` function work, for example).

Note that `scanf` and `malloc` can fail, so consider how your program would look if it were to handle those situations. Here is a toy example in which we assume they never do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *booking(int *val) {
    int dokter;

    printf("Silahkan pilih Dokter yang tersedia\n"
            "1. Dr. Saburo\n"
            "2. Dr. Bineka\n"
            "3. Dr. Saskeh\n"
            "4. Dr. Lur Bor\n"
            "5. Dr. Frutang\n");

    printf("Pilih (1/2/3/4/5) >: ");
    scanf("%d", &dokter);

    if (dokter == 1) {
        puts("Hari yang tersedia : Senin, Rabu, Kamis, Jumat");
    } else if (dokter == 2) {
        puts("Hari yang tersedia : Selasa, Rabu, Jumat, Sabtu");
    } else if (dokter == 3){
        puts("Hari yang tersedia : Senin, Rabu, Kamis, Sabtu, Minggu");
    } else if (dokter == 4) {
        puts("Hari yang tersedia : Senin, Kamis, Jumat");
    } else if (dokter == 5) {
        puts("Hari yang tersedia : Selasa, Rabu, Sabtu, Minggu");
    } else {
        puts("Invalid");
    }

    char *jadwal = malloc(100);

    printf("Jadwal >: ");
    scanf("%*c%99[^\n]", jadwal);

    *val = dokter;

    return jadwal;
}

int main(void) {
    int number;
    char *string = booking(&number);

    printf("String: [%s]; Number: %d\n", string, number);

    free(string);
}
```

Comment: Worth a comment that it is recommended to take all user input with `fgets()` and parse with `sscanf()` (if needed), otherwise just strip the newline with `strcspn()` for use as a string. That avoids all hacks to handle the trailing `'\n'` like `scanf("%*c%99[^\n]", jadwal);`. However, what you have, on balance, is a big improvement.